# How can I make the read only file system writable on BusyBox?

Tags: busybox

I want to change some files on my router. Firstly I can change everything in `/var`, but I want to change `/etc/fstab`. When I try to change it, I get an error message that says the file system is read only.

BusyBox inside the router has limited commands, so I got a [BusyBox binary for MIPs](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.19.0/busybox-mips), and uploaded it by tftp:

```
tftp -g -r busybox-mips my.i.p.addr
```

I can now use full commands (/var/tmp/busybox-mips command).

There is no ROM inside the router (SDRAM), nor is there any other partition. It must be related with BusyBox.

```
# /var/tmp/busybox-mips df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 1344      1344         0 100% /

# mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nodiratime)
ramfs on /var type ramfs (rw)
# 

Model: 
        Airties 5021
Processor:
        BCM6332KFBG
        HS1037 P12
        994981 N1
Memory: 
        M12L64164A-7T (SDRAM)
        ANM1P02HL 1028
```

Comment: What is the output of `mount` ?

Comment: Joel i updated my quiestion. sorry for delay, i cant post comments from my office.

Answer (score 1):

Squashfs is immutable. To change /etc/fstab you would need to make a new FS image for your router on a linux box. To get that on the router you do a "firmware upgrade".

You could also look in /proc/mounts to check whether `mount` is lying to you, as it only reads `/etc/mtab`. But the latter is in most distros a symbolic link.

Comment: hi Turbo J, 
I have checked /proc/mounts. It seems mountdisplays only /etc/mtab. 

I am confused in the "Frimware Upgrade" part. I think if you upgrade the firmware, then the system will still be readonly, won't it? So in my opinion I have to upgrade/change the FS. Do you know how to do that??

Comment: Even [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) knows `unsquashfs` and `mksquashfs`. Try Google next time.

Comment: The filesystem comes from the firmware.  You can't modify the filesystem unless you rebuild and reflash the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make the thing writable for the current session, but the change will not be persistent: once you reboot, your changes will get lost. To do this, you mount a tempfs somewhere, copy the content of `/etc` into it, then `mount --move` it to `/etc`.

If you need persistent changes, then you'll have to recreate your squashfs. Other answers already include more detail on this.